# Flask SQLAlchemy "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Please help me to solving this problem, I've tried various ways but it's always an error like this

**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))")
[SQL: SELECT chatgpt_field.id AS chatgpt_field_id, chatgpt_field.sender AS chatgpt_field_sender, chatgpt_field.question AS chatgpt_field_question, chatgpt_field.answer AS chatgpt_field_answer, chatgpt_field.source AS chatgpt_field_source, chatgpt_field.timestamp AS chatgpt_field_timestamp
FROM chatgpt_field ORDER BY chatgpt_field.timestamp DESC]**

This is my code

models.py

```
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
 import datetime
 
 db = SQLAlchemy() 

 class ChatHistory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'chatgpt_field'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender = db.Column(db.String(20))
    question = db.Column(db.Text)
    answer = db.Column(db.Text)
    source = db.Column(db.String(200))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.date.today)
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, jsonify, flash, url_for, Response
 from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
 from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
 from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
 from models import db
 from models import ChatHistory, User
 from chatbot import ChatGptDemo

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.static_folder = 'static'
 app.template_folder = 'templates' 

 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:''@localhost/db_chatgpt'

 with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)

 data_path = "./docs/"
 model_name = 'gpt-3.5-turbo-16k' #gpt-4
 chatgpt_demo = ChatGptDemo(data_path, model_name)
 chatgpt_demo.load_documents()
 chatgpt_demo.split_documents()
 chatgpt_demo.create_vector_store()
 chatgpt_demo.initialize_models()


 @app.route("/qna")
 def chatbot():
    title = "Chat GPT"
    js_file = "static\js\chat.js"
    return render_template('chatbot.html', js_file=js_file, title=title)


 @app.route("/chat")
 def get_bot_response():
    user_input = str(request.args.get('msg')).lower()
    result = None
    existing_entry = None
    start = time.time() 
    end = None
    
    for entry in ChatHistory.query.all():
        existing_question = entry.question.lower()
        corpus = [user_input, existing_question]
        vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
        tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
        cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix[1:2])

        if cosine_sim[0][0] > 0.7:
            existing_entry = entry
            break

    if existing_entry:
        result = {
            "code": 0,
            "result": {
                "text": existing_entry.answer,
                "documents": existing_entry.source,
            },
            "time_usage": 0,
            "meta": [],
        }
    else:
        try:
            responses = chatgpt_demo.run_conversational_retrieval_chain(user_input)
            end = time.time() 
            result = {
                "code": 0,
                "result": {
                    "text": responses["result"],
                    "documents": responses["source_file"],
                },
                "time_usage": end - start,
                "meta": [],
            }
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            print(str(e))
    
    if result is not None:
        chat_entry = ChatHistory(question=user_input, answer=result["result"]["text"],   source=result["result"]["documents"] if result else None)
        db.session.add(chat_entry)
        db.session.commit()

    return jsonify(result)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Solving the bug sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))") when running in production server